# Keycloak docker doesn't run

Tags: java, docker, jboss, keycloak

Anyone had any success with this? The README instructions fail as you can't have an empty DB_USER or DB_PASSWORD (according to the entry_point.sh script).

When I run it with the following command, it breaks with many errors.

`docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=b184353813254a69a6d8190df4aa7517     -e KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/example-realm.
json -e DB_USER=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD=keycloak -v /tmp/example-realm.json:/tmp/example-realm.json -p 8080:8080 jboss/keycloak`

the errors seem to start with

`ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment: o
rg.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public 
org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)`

and just continue. This worked literally last week, so I don't know what's changed.

Comment: you need to check jboss logs, looks like can't start application. try running with in0memory database, like: docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e DB_VENDOR=H2 -p 8080:8080 --name sso jboss/keycloak-examples

Comment: Are there any stack traces in the log? Have you analysed the log for a root cause exception?